# Windows 11 keeps disconnecting my monitor when I connect my TV

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11

I have the following configuration: LG Monitor on Displayport, Acer Monitor on HDMI, LC C2 TV on HDMI, all connected to my 3070.

Now, whenever I turn on my TV, Win11 tries to revert back to my old monitor config which is TV only, all Monitors disabled. I want to be able to switch the monitor config via a script, so that I can switch between TV only or Monitors only. To do that, I am using multimonitortool, created the two configs that I want, saved them and have a script that calls the tool and tells it to load the requested config.

The problem is, whenever I turn on my TV, Win11 behaves in a weird way and seemingly completely disables my LG monitor. When I run the multimonitortool script, it is still not able to re-enable that LG monitor, I have to manually go into Windows Display settings and tell Windows to extend to that monitor.

Why does this keep happening? Is there any way to tell windows to not disable monitors when my TV is plugged in, so I can let my script enable/disable what I want?

Comment: Could you give details on what was the "old monitor config" and how it was defined?

Comment: "Old" = before I connect the TV. So in my case its the LG ultrawide + 1080p monitor. As soon as my TV turns on, my PC disabled those two monitors and only the TV is enabled. I then have to go to the display settings and manually re-enable the other monitors.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode ? What are the resolutions and frequencies?